# Is it possible to download working image from live server and run it as local?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a project which runs on oro commerce within 2 docker containers:

- web
- database

I tried to launch project without containers on apache. I always get problems with extensions and other stuff, now I have 2 tasks.

1. I need to launch project locally and migrate it to another live server. What are my options? (I really dont know much about docker) Is it possible to download all ready containers or images and run it locally? Where should I look to build a picture with steps for a task?
2. I managed to pull project from git and tried to docker-compose it, but it seems it is loading images from github or something
   I will leave docker-compose file below

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  database:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/ubiedigital/kauno-grudai/server/database:latest
    container_name: database
    networks:
    - kggroup_default
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    volumes:
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    restart: always

  web-stage:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/ubiedigital/kauno-grudai/server/web:latest
    container_name: web-stage
    networks:
    - kggroup_default
    ports:
    - 8000:80
    - 4434:443
    volumes:
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - ./html-stage/crm:/var/www/html
    environment:
    - SERVER_NAME=${SERVER_NAME}
    - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
    - ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
    depends_on:
    - database
    restart: always

  web-master:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/ubiedigital/kauno-grudai/server/web:latest
    container_name: web-master
    networks:
    - kggroup_default
    ports:
    - 8080:80
    - 4433:443
    volumes:
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - ./html-master/crm:/var/www/html
    environment:
    - SERVER_NAME=${SERVER_NAME}
    - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
    - ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
    depends_on:
    - database
    restart: always

networks:
  kggroup_default:
    name: kggroup_default
```

Answer (score 0):

Containers are not downloaded.
There are docker images in a docker image server. This server can be registry.gitlab.com, dockerhub or whatever.

Then, containers are instances of those docker images.
So, when you do `docker compose up -d`, you're automatically downloading these images and creating containers in your local.

In order to install it in other servers, you've just to execute again the deploy command (`docker-compose up -d` with what parameters you need, such as environment setting) in other servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can export and import your docker image.
First, stop your container then
Find the name of the container that you would like to move

```
$ docker ps -a
```

then

```
$ docker save mycontainername > /path/to/folder/mycontainername.tar
```

Export mycontainername.tar on your new location

then

```
$ docker load mycontainername < /path/to/folder/mycontainername.tar
```